# Efficient replace value by value in other column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to replace one column by another if the values in that column are equal to a string. The value of this string is "wo". If this shows up in column y, replace by column x.
Currently I use the following code:

```
df.y.replace("wo",df.x)
```

This runs for a very long time (millions of observations, equals days of calculations).

Is there a more efficient way to replace ?

Just in case, the data looks as follows:

```
 y    x    other variables
 1    mo    something
 2    2     something
 3    3     something
 wo   >5    something
 4    4     something
 wo   7     something
```

It has to look like:

```
 y    x    other variables
 1    mo    something
 2    2     something
 3    3     something
 >5   >5   something
 4    4     something
 7    7     something
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try this:

```
df.loc[(df.y == 'wo'), 'y'] = df.x
```

it will first filter only those rows where `df.y == 'wo'` and will assign `x` column's value to 'y' column

Timeit report:

```
In [304]: %timeit df.y.replace("wo",df.x)
100 loops, best of 3: 13.9 ms per loop

In [305]: %timeit df.loc[(df.y == 'wo'), 'y'] = df.x
100 loops, best of 3: 3.31 ms per loop

In [306]: %timeit df.ix[(df.y == 'wo'), 'y'] = df.x
100 loops, best of 3: 3.31 ms per loop
```

---

**UPDATE:** starting from Pandas 0.20.1 [the .ix indexer is deprecated, in favor of the more strict .iloc and .loc indexers](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew.html#deprecate-ix).

Comment: Do you have an indication that this actually speeds something up? If it does, I think it should be filed as a performance bug for `pd`'s `replace` method.

Comment: I will test speed now.

Comment: @MaxU Hmm, interesting.

Comment: Just tested it for speed. My original code is still running (and considering this is 99,99% of the code that has been running for over a week it probably will be for a while). Your code finished in a couple of minutes. Insane performance upgrade, thank you !!!

Comment: @Peter, i'm glad i could help

Comment: @Peter you'll have slightly speed performance by doing `df.y[df.y=='wo'] = df.x`

Answer (score 2):

First, Pandas should be notified that that string value "wo" represents IEEE double NaN (aka numpy nan etc). See for example the `na_values` parameter of the `read_csv` method [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html). This will allow the entire column to be stored as `double` which will increase efficiency. Then use something like [this](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/missing_data.html#values-considered-missing) to replace the NaN values with the values from the other column.

Comment: I assume this means that other non-numerics have to also be converted to na ? There can be several symbols and letter combinations in there. While converting them is not a problem for the letter combinations (although I assume I have to mention them all specifically?) sometimes the number is >5. This would make it trickier ? (sorry for incompletely specifying this in the question)

Comment: I have used the `na_values` extensively and IF these values really are irrelevant and should be replaced, then they can be specified in iterable form (think list) to that argument. If the values are not irrelevant then depending on the source, the information they provide should perhaps be put off into another categorical data column with N/A values fed into the original column. Edit: the ">5" is not a problem because that doesn't parse as a double.